# How do you pass arguments to a rake task in RubyMine 3.0?

Tags: ruby, rake, rubymine

**The situation**

I have a rake task similar to

```
desc "A rake Task"
task :give_me_gold, [:quantity,:quality] => :environment do |task, args|
 ....
end
```

I am aware from the commandline you type

```
rake give_me_gold[10,24]
```

to pass parameters to the rake task.  However when RubyMine runs the task it runs it like this:

```
rake give_me_gold[quantity,quality] --trace 10,24
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create a rake task that takes arguments.
2. Have RubyMine installed version 3.0
3. From RubyMine, click *Tools* -> *Run Rake Task*
4. Input your rake task name. It should show up as "task[option,option]" and press enter
5. A dialog will show up and ask for arguments. Fill it in and press enter
6. Observe the command RubyMine runs.

**Back to my question**

How do you pass arguments to a rake task in RubyMine 3.0?

*Thank you for taking the time to view this question*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in RubyMine. See [Issue #8527](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-8527?projectKey=RUBY&query=rake%20task) at jetbrains.net

Answer (score 1):

```
task :give_me_gold do
  quantity = ENV['quantity']
  quality  = ENV['quality']
  puts "quantity: #{quantity}, quality: #{quality}"
end 

rake give_me_gold quantity=10 quality=24
#=> quantity: 10, quality: 24
```

**upd**

```
task :give_me_gold, :quantity, :quality do |t, args|
  puts "Args were: #{args}"
  quantity = args['quantity']
  quality  = args['quality']
  puts "quantity: #{quantity}, quality: #{quality}"
end

rake give_me_gold[10,24]
#=> quantity: 10, quality: 24
```

Comment: Standard practice for passing arguments to rake task as always been as illustrated in my question. Passing arguments to the rake task as environment variables seems counter to the standard.

Comment: Actually, I don't have RubyMine, so I am out of topic :(

Answer (score 0):

The good approach to pass inputs along with environment is:

**task :upload, [:path] => [:environment]  do |t, args|

```
puts args
YOUR_MODEL.method(args)
```

end
**